# flutter/dart value from Map

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get a single value from a nested map.
In this case, the value of the postal_code: 52034

Map:

```
{plus_code: {compound_code: QW8C+JTA ExampleTown, ExampleCountry, global_code: 8FFGDSC+JTA}, 
results: [
    {address_components: [{long_name: 31, short_name: 31, types: [street_number]}, 
    {long_name: ExampleRoute, short_name: ExampleRoute, types: [route]}, 
    {long_name: ExampleTown, short_name: ExampleTown, types: [locality, political]}, 
    {long_name: ExampleCountry, short_name: DE, types: [country, political]}, 
    {long_name: 52034, short_name: 52034, types: [postal_code]}
], 
formatted_address: ExampleRoute 31, 52034 ExampleTown, ExampleCountry, geometry: {location: {lat: 12.345678, lng: 12.345678}, locati
```

maybe something like:

```
print(data["results"][0]["address_components"]...???..);
```

Comment: decode with json decoder then do it step by step, for eg : var a = data['results']; var b = a[0];, var c = b['address_components']; , print (c) ;    or (Othe way is to  use MODEL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data["results"][0]["address_components"].length; i++) {
  if(data["results"][0]["address_components"][i]["types"].toString() == "[postal_code]"){
    print(data["results"][0]["address_components"][i]["long_name"].toString(););
  }
}
```